# React Redux can't resolve its own modules

Tags: javascript, npm, react-redux

When I run webpack for my project, I get this error suggesting that the React-Redux package can't resolve some of its internal modules:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Context' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 3:0-57 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Provider' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 1:0-45 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/connectAdvanced' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 2:0-59 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './connect/connect' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 4:0-40 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './hooks/useDispatch' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 5:0-70 12:0-179 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './hooks/useSelector' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 6:0-70 12:0-179 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './hooks/useStore' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 7:0-61 12:0-179 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './utils/batch' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 8:0-41 11:0-8
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './utils/reactBatchedUpdates' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 9:0-79 11:9-14 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './utils/shallowEqual' in '/home/.../frontend/src/node_modules/react-redux/es'
 @ ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 10:0-48 12:0-179
 @ ./index.tsx
```

Does anyoe have any idea how to resolve this? Could it possibly be because I installed react-redux before redux? If so, how could I fix it. I already tried deleting `package-lock.json` and deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm install`. I also dug into the filesystem and found that the unresolvable modules exist on the filesystem; for example, even though webpack can't resolve `./components/Provider`, the file `node_modules/react-redux/es/Provider.js` exists and looks fine.

Here is the relevant part of `package.json`. Could it be a version mismatch or something?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.9",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.4.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4",
    "typescript-eslint": "0.0.1-alpha.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
```

Comment: TBH,  it does not matter which you install first,  it could be a tsx issue, also have you tried removing the module and reinstalling

Comment: Could you please show the part of the code where you import `react-redux`? I think you might be importing `react-redux/es` instead of `react-redux`.

Comment: @AntonTuyakhov I updated the original post with my `package.json`, and inside index.tsx, the code I used to import react-redux looks normal `import { Provider } from 'react-redux';`

Comment: It was a webpack issue. :facepalm:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Awesome, I finally got it to work! What did the trick in the end was deleting the whole project folder and re-installing it from GitHub. There must have been something wrong with the installed `node_modules` that even `rm -rf` couldn't fix.

---

EDIT: I lied. Apparently, when I deleted the project and reloaded it from GitHub, I accidentally reset the commit where I had added all of the Redux stuff, and as soon as I brought it back, the error returned as well. What *actuallly* happened was an error in my `webpack.config.js` file:

What I had was `"extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"]`

What I needed was `"extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]`

Thus, even though the JS files were there, Webpack had been ignoring them because the `".js"` extension was missing from my config file. Adding in those four characters fixed the problem. And so ends a several-hour-long session of debugging. Hope this helps anyone else stupid enough to screw up their Webpack config and then try to use it to load React-Redux.